# how to call a function of a same class from other functions of the same class-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

But i'm getting errors when declaring like this.

```
@implementation data

-(void)SwapEndian:(uint8_t*)pData withBOOLValue:(bool)bIsAlreadyLittleEndian
{
data* datas = [data alloc];
[datas swapEndians:(uint8_t)&pData[nIndex] withSize:(sizeof(uint32_t));  
}

-(void)swapEndians:(uint8_t*)pData withnByteSize:(int const)nByteSize
{
    NSLog(@"swapEndians!!");
}

@end
```

How to call a function from other function inside the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **self** keyword to achieve this.

> [self yourFunctionName];

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

> ```
> data* datas = [data alloc]; // Where is your init? Don't use un-initialized objects!
> [datas swapEndians:(uint8_t)&pData[nIndex] withSize:(sizeof(uint32_t));
> ```

Second thing:
If the method you are trying to call is the second one from you code, you have a typo in the selector!
That line should read:

```
[datas swapEndians:&pData[nIndex] withnByteSize:sizeof(uint32_t)];
```

Third thing:
You send messages to yourself by using `self`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all class name should start with capital letter, here is I think you are tying to do

```
    @implementation Data //changed it just naming convention 

    -(void)swapEndian:(uint8_t*)pData withBOOLValue:(bool)bIsAlreadyLittleEndian
      {
         [self swapEndians:(uint8_t)&pData[nIndex] withSize:(sizeof(uint32_t));  
      }

    -(void)swapEndians:(uint8_t*)pData withnByteSize:(int const)nByteSize
      {
        NSLog(@"swapEndians!!");
      }

    @end
```

Comment: ... and message names should start from lowercase letter